# Do I need to set download speed limit for concurent downloads (using cURL) or they will take equal shares?

Tags: linux, unix, networking, ubuntu, curl

My website (run under ubuntu 10,04) enables users to grab files from web links .. 
Do I need to set a download rate limit per single file , so all can download at the same time ?
And also , do I need to set a global download limit (for all files together) so that my server connection can handle other requests of downloading files directly from my server , browsing my website ...etc ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate limit curl supports is set per "handle", which makes it per single transfer.

Networks in general are designed to handle many connections sharing a tight shared resource, so in most situations you won't need to limit any transfer rates at all.